# Fitting zero inflated poisson to plot it in R

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-distribution

I have the following data

```
data<-c(1L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 13L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 13L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 
4L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 
2L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 13L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 18L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 
9L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 3L, 24L, 11L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 17L, 
11L, 11L, 8L, 2L, 14L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 
15L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 7L, 3L, 20L, 17L, 14L, 
7L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 7L, 18L, 13L, 
18L, 20L, 16L, 9L, 5L, 13L, 16L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 21L, 
9L, 7L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 13L, 19L, 17L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 18L, 14L, 
8L, 8L, 16L, 13L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 20L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 8L, 16L, 10L, 
9L, 20L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 16L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 20L, 5L, 2L, 21L, 16L, 
18L, 0L, 16L, 4L, 6L, 16L, 6L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 22L, 14L, 
5L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 12L, 6L, 20L, 10L, 
17L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 15L, 18L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 16L, 
16L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 20L, 16L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 10L, 8L, 17L, 
24L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 9L, 10L, 22L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 16L, 7L, 
12L, 10L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 16L, 13L, 4L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 11L, 4L, 
3L, 10L, 19L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 
7L, 13L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 
12L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 
6L, 11L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 
6L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 
4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 17L, 15L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 16L, 17L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 14L, 
2L, 17L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 1L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 
3L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 
8L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 
4L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 14L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 6L, 
5L, 12L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
8L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
7L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 
8L, 27L, 8L, 12L, 20L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 
13L, 10L, 14L, 14L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 23L, 7L, 12L, 
6L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 16L, 10L, 11L, 18L, 7L, 15L, 18L, 10L, 
9L, 15L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 9L, 
7L, 9L, 15L, 7L, 7L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 22L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 
12L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 16L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 
4L, 14L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 
8L, 12L, 7L, 13L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 
9L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 
10L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
5L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 11L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 11L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 
14L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 
9L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 
1L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
20L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 17L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 
1L)
```

I have run a ZINB model and I know that it is the best fit for my data. I want to demonstrate on a graph that this distribution is my best option. I am using `fitdist`

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(gamlss)

nb<-fitdist(data, "nbinom")
pois<-fitdist(data, "pois")
zinb<-fitdist(data, 'ZANBI',start = list(mu = 4, sigma = 0.2))
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot.legend <- c("Negative binomial", "Poisson", "ZINB")
```

My problem is that, just as I wanted to demonstrate that `nbinom` and `pois` are not the best fit, I can't do it with zero inflated poisson`ZIP`.

I am using `gamlss`

```
zip<-fitdist(data, 'ZIP',start = list(mu = 7.09, sigma = 4.5))
```

Here I'm using the values suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782612/zero-inflated-poisson-distribution-fail-to-estimate-the-parameter-with-error-co) considering  `mean(data[data != 0])` and  `var(data[data != 0])`. I always get:

```
Error in fitdist(data, "ZIP", start = list(mu = 7.09, sigma = 4.5)) : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In fitdist(data, "ZIP", start = list(mu = 7.09, sigma = 4.5)) :
  The dZIP function should return a zero-length vector when input has length zero and not raise an error
2: In fitdist(data, "ZIP", start = list(mu = 7.09, sigma = 4.5)) :
  The pZIP function should return a zero-length vector when input has length zero and not raise an error
```

I also used `mu=7.09` and `sigma=0.217` [as this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618624/issue-with-fitting-zero-inflated-poisson-in-r) suggests to calculate de values

How can I plot a ZIP of my values to demonstrate is not the best fit?